# Statement vs Expression in Rust

Tags: rust

I just started to learn Rust using the official document.
In chapter 3 I have a little confusion about expression vs statement.
In the following statement:

```
let y = {
    let x = 9;
    x + 1
};
```

`x + 1` is an expression. If I add `;` at the end it is a statement. According to the doc "Expressions do not include ending semicolons".
However in the following code block:

```
let result = loop {
    counter += 1;

    if counter == 10 {
        break counter + 1;
    }
};
```

result gets a value 11, I am not sure how  `break counter + 1;` is evaluated as a expression even though i have a `;` at the end? I am sure I am missing something but not sure what it is. Without the `;` the code executes and result gets 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not sure how `break counter + 1;` is evaluated as a expression even though i have a ; at the end?

It's not, `break counter + 1;` is a statement. `break counter + 1` [is an expression](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/loop-expr.html#break-expressions).

Although that lexical analysis doesn't really matter (except insofar as you can put `break` essentially anywhere in your program unlike e.g. in Python) because it *diverges*: `break`, `continue`, `return`, ... never return a yield a value, instead they immediately alter control flow and jump to some other part of the program. So their "return type" is [never (`!`)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.never.html).

`result` gets a value of 11 not because `break` is an expression, but because the entire point of `break <value>` is to abort the `loop` with the specified value as result.

If you want the full details of Rust's lexical analysis, it is detailed in [the Rust Reference chapter 8](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/statements-and-expressions.html).